# Look for multiple words in string

Tags: vba

Need to build a VBA function that simulates the `REGEXP_INSTR` or `REGEXP_LIKE` in Oracle. Those make possible to look for words in string without having to loop word by word.

I've found this code, that find Names that starts with "Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr", that meant to be used like:

```vb
Function StringStarts(strCheck As String, options As String) As Boolean
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "^(" & options & ")\.*\b"

        StringStarts = .Test(strCheck)
    End With
End Function
```

```vb
Debug.print StringStarts("Dr leopoldo malmeida", "Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr")
```

In fact, I need help to find if it's possible to alter this function, in order to find any word, or parts of words (case-insensitive matching), in the pattern on any location of the string to search. For example:

```vb
Debug.print StringStarts("Looking for multiple words", "Word|like|for")
```

That should return true: "Word found in 'words'"; "for was a complete match in string".

Comment: So that would be `.Pattern = options`.

Comment: Consider calling it `StringStartsWith`, and making the 2nd parameter a `ParamArray` (needs to be Variant) - that way you can do `Debug.Print StringStartsWith(someString, "possibility1", "possibility2", "possibility3", "possibility4")`, and with little tweaks you can make it work with an array

Comment: Is it supposed to return a boolean, or your example strings?

Comment: Could just return a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Most probably RegEx is not needed, because it is a bit slow. A simple for-each loop in a function would be ok:

```
Public Function PatternPresent(testedString As String, _
                                Optional pattern As String = "Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr") As Boolean

    Const separator = "|"
    Dim patterns As Variant: patterns = Split(pattern, separator)
    Dim myVar As Variant

    For Each myVar In patterns
        If InStr(1, testedString, myVar) Then
            PatternPresent = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next myVar

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Vityata, for your help. I've really appreciated.

Comment: I need to compare string similarity between two tables - Table A (16888 records) and Table B (1.234.567 records). The process compares each one of table A with each one in the table B. This function is meant to select from table B those who has at least two words matched, to reduce the process of string similarity evaluation.

Comment: @LEOPOLDO - this looks like 20000 million+ comparisons. In a database, this would be a standard task, if the databases are indexed correctly.